# HTML5 Canvas 2D Frameworks focusing on collision detection and physics

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks, collision-detection

I am looking for the best way to manage objects within the canvas context. For my first project I am looking to do the following:

1. Draw the ground.
2. Drop a circle onto the ground with collision detection and elasticity.
3. Have the circle "explode" subtracting the ground below it(Explosion that alters the ground giving a crater like look).

So basically what is the best way to track objects that then get altered by other objects. I'm guessing you could track all of the changes to an object in an array, but I was curious if there are any good frameworks for something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is the Javascript 2D Game Engine
which can be found here
http://www.lukewallin.co.uk/?go=engine
Here's a demo:
http://www.lukewallin.co.uk/singleplayer_games/sandbox4/sandbox.php?id=21
It even has explosions :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to build a tank game (weapons that destroy ground), you're best bet is to not actually track the location of what is/is not ground since you're going to end up with absurd shapes. Instead, use a canvas and the image of the ground itself as that object. Canvas has methods to get a pixel color at a specific point that you can use to check "is there ground here". Your explosion would then simply erase part of the canvas and you'd run a loop to make any floating ground "fall"

If you do this, I'd suggest putting the ground itself in a separate canvas element from any other elements so that you can have effects/units/etc on top of the ground without interfering with your collision detection.

Comment: Ah I see, thats a good idea. So if a circle with a radius of 10 is heading to the ground object would you check every pixel inside the circle for color matches or just every pixel around the edge of the circle? And you guessed perfectly. Trying to mimick the old tank game scorch for a fun first game :)

Comment: You can actually check significantly less than that.  If you check the 4 points at 90deg to the circle, you're going to get very good collision detection, if you check a few more, say 10, you'll get collision detection nearly indistinguishable from "full" detection.  You can also optimize it so that you only check the "forward half" of the circle.  Post results when you're done :)

Comment: Awesome. I am looking to do this as efficient as possible and this already gave me a few great ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look into the [box2d port for javascript](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) to use with html5's canvas element. I've used it for flash in the past and it is a solid engine. It will do all the collision and physics for you so all you would have to do is listen for the callbacks and change the image accordingly.

Comment: I have seen this, but I was unsure how it handled explosion type events (adding or subtracting shapes to other shapes). Thanks for the suggestion!